# Find li on newly prepended item

Tags: jquery

My application adds new posts to an `<ul>` using .prepend() and then uses the .ajax() function to add it to the database like so:

```
$("#add input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    newPost = $("#add textarea").val();
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST", 
        url     : "/add", 
        data    : { "post" : newPost },
        success: function(data) {               

           $('#posts ul').prepend('<li id="1234"><p>'+newPost+'<p><span class="delete">Delete</span></li>');
        }
});
```

This works as intended, but as you can see I have a Delete button for each post and I delete post using the following jquery:

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    var thiscache = $(this),
    post_id = thiscache.closest("li").find("p").attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST", 
        url     : "/delete", 
        data    : { "post_id" : post_id },

        success : function(r){ 
            thiscache.parent().slideUp('slow'); 
            },

    });
});
```

Delete will work with post that have been added previously, but if you add a post using the ajax form, and click delete nothing fires. What could be the cause of this? Maybe the new post `<li>` isn't in the DOM?

I created a JSfiddle without the Ajax functions. http://jsfiddle.net/bhhgf
If you add a new post it will append it, but you can not delete it. Deleting the current posting works just fine.

EDIT:

I also use jeditable with a custom event, but .live() will not tigger new post.

```
$("p").editable('/edit/save', {event : 'edit_button'});

$(".edit").live('click', function(){       
    $(this).closest("li").find("p").trigger('edit_button');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the dynamically added elements to the DOM you need to rebind the event handler to them or use `.live` or `.delegate`

```
$(".delete").live('click',function(){

});
```

or

```
$("#posts ul").delegate(".delete","click",function(){

});
```

[`jquery live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

[`jquery delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

for the `edit` link in your first `ajax` callback again call the `jeditable` on the desired elements

```
    $("#add input[type=submit]").click(function(){
        newPost = $("#add textarea").val();
        $.ajax({
            type    : "POST", 
            url     : "/add", 
            data    : { "post" : newPost },
            success: function(data) {               

               $('#posts ul').prepend('<li id="1234"><p>'+newPost+'<p><span class="delete">Delete</span></li>');
             //call editable here on the desired elements
             $("p").editable('/edit/save', {event : 'edit_button'});
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function.  This will apply the handler to all current and future elements which match the given selector.  Thus, your new elements appended to the document will have the handler attached to `click`.

```
 $(".delete").live('click', function(){
   var thiscache = $(this),
   post_id = thiscache.closest("li").find("p").attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      type    : "POST", 
      url     : "/delete", 
      data    : { "post_id" : post_id },

      success : function(r) { 
          thiscache.parent().slideUp('slow'); 
      },
   });
 });
```

Alternatively, you can just add the handler when you add new elements, e.g.:

```
 var deleteHandler = function() {
   var thiscache = $(this),
   post_id = thiscache.closest("li").find("p").attr("id");

   $.ajax({
      type    : "POST", 
      url     : "/delete", 
      data    : { "post_id" : post_id },

      success : function(r) { 
          thiscache.parent().slideUp('slow'); 
      },
   });
 });

 $(".delete").click(deleteHandler);

 $("#add input[type=submit]").click(function(){
   newPost = $("#add textarea").val();
   $.ajax({
     type    : "POST", 
     url     : "/add", 
     data    : { "post" : newPost },
     success: function(data) {               

     el = $('#posts ul').prepend('<li id="1234"><p>'+newPost+'<p><span class="delete">Delete</span></li>');
     el.find('.delete').click(deleteHandler);
   });
 });
```

This approach will selectively add handlers as it comes up.

Comment: [Why You Should Never Use jQuery Live](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live)

Comment: Thanks! I also have an Edit button that uses jEditable, and the live doesn't seem to work with that. Please see my edit above ^

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event is only bound for the elements that exist at that time. The elements that you add after that are not affected.

Use the `delegate` method to bind the event handler to a parent element, so that events from newly added elements are also handled:

```
$("'#posts ul").delegate(".delete", "click", function(){
  ...
```

#### Edit:

The editable plugin doesn't work with `delegate` as it's not just an event handler. You would have to apply that to the list element after adding it:

```
$("#" + id + " p").editable('/edit/save', {event : 'edit_button'});
```

where `id` contains the id of the list element that you prepended. (`"1234"` in your example, but your actual id should not be only digits...)

Comment: Can you comment on why my id should not be only digits? Thank you.

Comment: @Char Whitaker: An id should start with a letter, according to the HTML standard. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.2

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to use the live event like the prior poster says, but there is also an error in your add method because you put the id attribute on the li element, but in your html, you have the id attribute on the p element.

Comment: Yeah, I that was more of a typo. I tried to provide the least amount of code in the question. The production code works. Thanks for the heads up though.